# Should I lose support for so many devices when targeting API 31 for Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-api-31

I last updated the Android app I work on in June, and now it says that I need to target API version 31. After doing so (via Unity), my new release says I'll lose support for 80-90% of devices. That seems pretty extreme, so I just wanted to confirm that that's intentional, as opposed to some mistake I might have made.

[image]

Comment: What did you update? You need to update the `targetSdk` which does not impact the minimum supported version. That would be the `minSdk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity I had the Target API Version set to "highest installed", which was API level 30, even though API level 33 was an explicit option. Setting it manually to API level 31 resolved this.